# Issuing commands (stdin) to an already running process using PHP

Tags: stdin, psexec, bukkit

I got this process running doing some server-related tasks. I'd like to have PHP issue a command to it.

The software I'm using is Craftbukkit which is a custom server tool for Minecraft. I'd like to be able to execute various commands to it using PHP. I'm using psexec to open it.

**EDIT:** I just figured by doing some more googling, that this is called "sending stdin to a process". So yeah, though you'd like to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using [WebSend](http://dev.bukkit.org/server-mods/websend/) which allows me todo just about this. I also think this solution seems a bit more safe.